# Read sms list on react native (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, sms, inbox

I'm currently building a React Native application **with expo** that should be able to read sms inbox and show it in the app.

I tried many libraries but none of them is **compatible with expo and newer version** of react/react-native

- [react-native-read-sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-read-sms)
- [react-native-get-sms-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-sms-android)
- [react-native-sms-retriever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever)
- [maniac-tech/react-native-expo-read-sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@maniac-tech/react-native-expo-read-sms)

I want two functionality for my app

1. Reading SMS of specific number
2. Event lisener on retrieve message